# chose connection pool based on parameter node mysql restful

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, connection-pooling

We are trying to create backend - RESTFUL api based on mysql DB - in express Nodejs. My boss (self acclaimed mysql guru) insist that we should use more connection pools than 1 - based on the different roles that users are grouped in.

So I need to define/create different connection pools in file B.js - > and make them as global variables so that I could access them later.
In file A.js  I have a this route - in which looged in users will be able to call stored procedures with arguments. However, I would like to be able to define from which connection pool the connection will be called - in route itself (based on the session (`req.user.role`) variable).

So that:

```
pool1.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
            return;
        }   
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
        connection.query(query1, val, function (err, rows, fields) {
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
                var results = JSON.stringify(rows[0]);
                console.log(results);
                console.log(typeof(results));
                console.log(rows[0][0]);
                console.log(typeof(rows[0]));
                res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
            }           
        });
        connection.on('error', function(err) { 
            connection.release();
            res.json({"code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database"});
            return;     
            });
    });



    });
};
```

refers to pool1, but in case with other user -> pool1 should connect to other pool - defined in other files.
I hope I am clear with my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use global variables, you can export an object that holds each pool:

```
// B.js
module.exports = {
  regular : mysql.createPool({ ... }),
  admin   : mysql.createPool({ ... }),
};

// A.js
const pools = require('./B');
...
let pool = pools[req.user.role];
if (! pool) {
  throw Error('there is no pool for user role ' + req.user.role);
}
pool.getConnection(...);
```

So this declares two pools, one for "regular" users and one for "admin" users. It uses the value of `req.user.role` (which is assumed to contain one of two values: "regular" or "admin", but that's just for the purpose of this example) to pick the pool that should be used.

I'm not sure what the upside is of having more than one pool, unless they connect to two different databases or use different database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're doing this or your boss want to do this, more connection pools won't make the application more efficient, it just confuse people. Since the MySQL server has its limit of clients. And by the way, if you want to know a user's role, you have to connect the database and fetch the user data in the first place. Why don't you just use the same connection to do other things and that will be fine.

Comment: The whole business logic is in our mysql - so he keeps insisting that users  should only have access to those stored procedures that have privileges for that.

Comment: If you don't want the user who is not permitted to access those stored procedures, just don't call the procedures in the program, there is no need to create another pool for that.

Answer (score -1):

We have more than one UI developer, each develops one role so we don't want that all UI developers can see all store procedures...  (That boss)

Comment: Sorry, is this an answer to the OP question? If not, please add it as a comment.